# How to get Image width/height of Image in Slidehow (To resize it and place it in center of div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am facing an Issue to add margin/padding if image size is less than allotted Image div size.

**Requirement**:

If image size is less then div size then add left/top margin so that It will be in center
Library: I am using [diapo.js](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/diapo/)

What I have did so far: I am taking whole Image present in slidehow and assigning margin to all images where size is less.

Problem here is when I loop over the whole image div using each function. we are not getting correct width and height of Image as dipo library adding display none (due to slidehow).

```
$('#imageDiv img').each(function(){  
    var theWidth = $(this).width();  
    var theHeight = $(this).height();  
    $(this).css({'margin-top': -theHeight / 2 + 'px', 'margin-left': -theWidth / 2 + 'px'});
});
```

I also tried to use when we display image. But fail :(

```
$('#wrapper > div:visible img').each(
        function(){
            var theWidth = $(this).width();
            var theHeight = $(this).height();
            $(this).attr("style","padding-left:"+(450-theWidth)/2+"px;padding-top:"+(338-theHeight)/2+"px");
            return;
        }
);
```

Please suggest If any one have did something or any Idea how to achieve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery for selecting by :visible is only going to run once and will not run when new slides become [in]visible. I would check into the `onEnterSlide` callback that the plugin provides and see if that will give you what you need. If that gives you the image when it becomes visible, it should work for you. Otherwise you may have to get your hands dirty and alter the source code yourself (if the license allows for it).